# Hadoop 2.6.0 HDFS Output Folder

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, cluster-computing, hdfs

I`m new to Hadoop. I setting up a hadoop-cluster with 1 Master and 3 Slaves. Everything is working fine so far. If I start a MapReduce Job the output folder isn`t set like do command says

```
hadoop jar TestApp.jar /hdfs/input /hdfs/output
```

but in /hdfs/ there is no output directory, it is in /user/hduser/hdfs/output
and I couldn`t get the result of the job.

Could someone please explain

Manuel

Comment: I think you have to use /user/hduser/hdfs/ as the input/output directory.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably this is because your are running the Hadoop command as `hduser`. Each Unix-like user has a HDFS *space* under `hdfs:///user/<username>`. Which is the result of a `whoami` command?

In order to access the result of the job, you will have to use Hadoop commands, I mean, a Unix-like `cat` command will not work, but a `hadoop fs -cat` or `hdfs dfs -cat` (complete reference [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html)).

Comment: sorry for answering late. the result of whoami is hduser. I restarted the cluster an now it works. temporarily i added the a query if the directory is set in in /hdfs/output or in /users/hduser/hdfs/outout.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe because you have logged in as hduser inside your machine, which is why it is taking hduser path. frb has clearly explained why this could possibly be the reason. What you can do now is you can give your input directory also in /user/hduser/hdfs/input path. so it will be in sync of all your directory